# Suppress output created by PowerShell New-Object

Tags: powershell, suppressmessage, new-object

Suppress PowerShell output messages new outlook application object is created?

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$outlookItem = $outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem")
```

I already tried using these approaches. They did not work:

```
 $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application > $Null
 $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application |Out-Null
 ($outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application) |Out-Null
```

These are the output message that I don't want them on the screen:

```
Application      : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class            : 5
...
...
```

Comment: When I run `$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application`, I don't see any output.  The object is created and assigned to `$outlook` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@boxdog, thanks for pointing it out.
After many break points, I noticed the output is produced by Attachments.Add() method. It is resolved using >$null.

```
$outlookItem.Attachments.Add("fileName.txt") > $null
```

Comment: Powershell-guru in their [Best Practice #12](http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-best-practice-12-avoid-out-null/): _it is recommended to **assign to `$null`** or **`[void]` casting** for better performance_.